# Javascript переменная не уменьшается в IF

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код на `jQuery`:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var g = $(".Group").length;
  alert(g + ' this G');
  var y = g;
  HELP = 1;
  $(".ClearFormG").each(function(index, element) {
    if (HELP < $(element).val()) {
      HELP = $(element).val();
      alert(HELP + ' in func');
    };

  });
  alert(HELP + " in setTime");
  if (g < HELP) {
    alert(g + ';' + HELP + ' if work');
    for (i = 0; i < (HELP - g); i++) {
      if (y == 40) break;
      $(".Group:last").clone(true).insertBefore('#AllSumP');
      y++;
      $(".groupNum:last").text(y);
      $(".CalcSum:last").text('');
    };

  } else if (HELP = g) {
    alert(g + ';' + HELP + ' elseif work');
    return;

  } else {
    while (g > x) {
      if (g == 1) break;
      alert('else work');
      $(".Group:last").remove();
      g--;
    };
  }


}, 3000);
```

он добавляет объекты если `g < HELP` и удаляет если `g > HELP`.
`alert(HELP + ' in func')` выводит всегда правильное значение

`alert(HELP + " in setTime")`  так же выводит правильное значение
а вот далее начинается театр

если `HELP > g`, то срабатывает `IF` и добавляются объекты и
 `alert(g + ';' + HELP + ' if work')` покажет правильное значение

если же 
`HELP < g`, то срабатывает `else if` и `alert(g + ';' + HELP + ' elseif work')` выводит одинаковые значение, хотя на вход было другое значение

Comment: Опечатка у Вас. Надо `==` вместо `=`.

Comment: @Yaant , спасибо
все Я поплыл видимо